# How to provide GUI interface to all users of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gui

I have "Ubuntu Dekstop" installed in VirtualBox in a Windows 7 PC.
How can I configure it to provide a GUI interface to every user I create in the Ubuntu?
Should I install "Ubuntu Server" to accomplish this?
Can this be done in Ubuntu? I remember working in a place where solaris was intalled in a server and every user used to login using cygwin and get a solaris GUI desktop.
Can this be done? And what is this feature called?

I am asking this for an event for the following purpose.
I want to install ruby on rails in an ubuntu machine and create 5 users in the ubuntu.
These 5 users will have their own Windows 7 laptops.
These 5 users should be able to get their own GUI desktop on their Windows 7 laptop.
And can this be done by installing Ubuntu in Virtual Box in a Windows 7 PC? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

*Screenshots and article structure from [“Connect to Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) via Windows Remote Desktop”](https://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/05/connect-to-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-via-windows-remote-desktop/) by [Richard W on the Liberian Geek blog](https://www.liberiangeek.net/author/liberiangeek/).*

You don't need to connect from cygwin anymore.

You can easily install `xrdp`  in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get insatll xrdp
```

And you can easily connect to the Ubuntu machine from your Windows machine using RDP protocol.

[image]

When prompted, type your Ubuntu username and password to connect.

[image]

Enjoy your Ubuntu.

[image]

If you have a problem when connecting so you get only a bare desktop without unity and the top panel you probably need to connect using ubuntu-2d session, so run the commands below and restart Ubuntu, then try again.

```
echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > ~/.xsession
```